# How can i get the correct gradle.startParameter.taskNames for an APK Build in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to increment the variable 'value' after clicking Build -> Build Bundles/APKs -> Build APK in Android Studio.

I modified my build.gradle like this:

```
def versionPropsFile = file('../gradle.properties')
def value = 0
def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames

Properties versionProps = new Properties()
...

if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'debug' in runTasks || 'release' in runTasks) {
    value = 1
}
```

But i never enter the if branch even though i check the conditions for debug and release too.

My goal would be to increment the variable only if i build a new APK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When i added following in build.gradle; it goes into 'if'

```
 defaultConfig {

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def value = 0
        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if(runTasks.toString().contains('assemble') || runTasks.toString().contains('debug') || runTasks.toString().contains('release')) {
            println "Yes all"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ranjan, Thank you very much. Do i have to define a Build Variant "release" in my project or define the runTasks?

Comment: 'release' and 'debug' are buildTypes. It is already present. runTasks are gradle tasks. when we run 'gradlew assembleDebug' or 'gradlew assembleRelease',; runTasks value will be 'assembleDebug'/'assembleRelease. To see list of gradle tasks run command 'gradlew tasks'.

Comment: Thanks Ranjan. That works fine for me. Great answer.